# How to determine the result of a SQL Server DB Backup?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am calling the following statement from withing a Stored Proc in SQL Server 2005.

```
Backup Database @dbname to disk = @dest
```

I need to be able to store the result of the 'Backup Database' in a variable so if something goes wrong I can kick off an alert to notify someone of the failure. 
How can I get that value?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the Backup Database command within a TRY block I believe. Simply add some code to email the error message in the catch block of the statement.